# How to integrate OWASP ZAP into GCP Cloud Build CI/CD

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build, owasp, zap

I am trying to run the OWASP ZAP baseline SCAN in my Cloud Build pipeline.
https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/docker/baseline-scan/#usage
I have found tutorials on how to do it this in Github, in Azure, and others but nothing in Cloud Build. Is there a better option for OWASP security testing?

This is what I have in my cloudRun.yaml file:

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  id: 'ZAP Proxy vulnerability scan'
  entrypoint: '/bin/sh'
  args: ['scripts/ZAP_OWASP_Run.sh','${PROJECT_ID}']
```

And this is what I have in the ZAP_OWASP_Run.sh:

`docker run -v $(pwd):/zap/wrk/:rw --user root -t owasp/zap2docker-stable zap-baseline.py -t https://myWebsite.com -T 5`

I had to add --user root because I was getting an error about permissions being denied.

This is kind of working but when I tried to add a config file to ignore certain warnings it broke again. I have had to hack this together that I started thinking I am going about this in the completely wrong way so I came to ask here.

Edit 1:
When I run the docker command without --user root I get the following error:

```
2023-01-23 23:22:34,992 Unable to copy yaml file to /zap/wrk/zap.yaml [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/zap/wrk/zap.yaml'
```

When I try to pass in a config file:

```
docker run -v $(pwd):/zap/wrk/:rw --user root -t owasp/zap2docker-stable zap-baseline.py -t https://radformation.com -T 5 -c zapAlerts.config
```

I get the following error:

```
2023-01-24 00:19:09,957 Failed to load config file /zap/wrk/zapAlerts.config not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)
```

EDIT 2: I got it working by first generating the config file locally and editing it, I tried to copy it from an online source originally.

My main question is, am I even doing this correctly? It feels very hacky. Is there a better way to ensure my website is OWASP compliant in GCP?

Comment: What perm errors were you getting running without root? We dont recommend running as root as then the browsers wont run, which mean you cant use the ajax spider or DOM XSS rule. Can you explain how it broke when you added the config file? Details are important :)

Comment: @SimonBennetts, Good point. I tried to add some more details. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Docker perms can be a complete pain. It looks like ZAP cannot update the directory mapped to `/zap/wrk/` - this will cause you lots of problems.
Try running `docker run -v $(pwd):/zap/wrk/:rw -t owasp/zap2docker-stable touch /zap/wrk/test.txt` - if that fails then its definitely a 'local' perm problem - once you get that simple case working then ZAP should run fine.

The `Failed to load config file /zap/wrk/zapAlerts.config not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)` error message means the file is in the wrong format. How did you create it?

FYI we have a Diagnosing Docker Problems page here: https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/docker/diagnosing-problems/